# How to query for SUM of multiple columns one-to-many

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
| Sales.Transaction
| ---------------
| Id
| Date
| BranchId
| Commission
|----------------


| Sales.TransactionItem
| ------------------
| Id
| Rate
| Pages
| TransactionId
|-------------------


| Sales.Branch
|-------------
| Id
| Name
|-------------
```

How can I get the `total sales of each Branches`, `total number of transactions` and `total pages`? I need to have a shape of data like this:

**NOTE**: `Total amount of Transaction, can be computed by getting the sum of TransactionItems(Rate * Pages) - Commission`

```
| Branches   | Total Sales | No. of Transactions | Total Pages      |
| Branch A   | 10,500      | 14                  |       17         |
| Branch B   |  5,200      |  4                  |        4         |
| Branch C   |    400      |  2                  |        2         |
| Branch D   |  6,100      |  8                  |       14         |
```

The problem with my query is that when the `Transaction` has a `Commission` and more than one `TransactionItems`, the `Commission` is being multiplied by the number of `TransactionItems`

```
select
    b.Name as BranchName,
    COUNT(t.Id) as Transactions,
    SUM(ti.Pages * ti.Rate) - SUM(t.Commission) as TotalSales,
    SUM(ISNULL(ti.Pages, 0)) as Pages
from 
    Sales.Branch b
        left join Sales.[Transaction] t 
            on b.Id = t.BranchId 
            and t.Date >= '2017-11-01'
            AND t.Date < '2017-12-01'
        left join Sales.TransactionItem ti
            on ti.TransactionId = t.Id
group by b.Name
order by b.Name ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky -- I think the solution is to aggregate the transaction items before joining the rest of the tables together:

```
select b.Name as BranchName,
       count(t.Id) as Transactions,
       sum(ti.total_minus_commission) - SUM(t.Commission) as TotalSales,
       sum(ti.total_pages) as Pages
from Sales.Branch b left join
     Sales.[Transaction] t 
     on b.Id = t.BranchId and
        t.Date >= '2017-11-01'
        t.Date < '2017-12-01' left join
     (select ti.TransactionId,
             sum(ti.Pages * ti.Rate) as total_minus_commission,
             sum(ti.Pages) as total_pages
      from Sales.TransactionItem ti
      group by ti.TransactionId
     ) ti
     on ti.TransactionId = t.Id
group by b.Name
order by b.Name ASC;
```

Note:  I also think this correctly calculates `Transactions`.

Comment: Thank you! I think it works great. Just a clarification, we need the SUM function here `sum(ti.total_minus_commission) - SUM(t.Commission) as TotalSales` in order to avoid the error on grouping which is important right?

Comment: @JaimeSangcap the missing `SUM` was my fault. I have spoiled his answer. It should be corrected now.